# Use entity name instead of ID in Rails nested routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I have the following routes defined:

```
resources :queues do
  resources :jobs
end
```

However, URLs will build like: `queues/:queue_id/jobs`. I would like them to build like `queues/:queue_name/jobs`. Where is the place to customize this behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#overriding-named-route-parameters),

> The :param option overrides the default resource identifier :id.

I.e.:

```
 resources :queues, param: :name do
   resources :jobs
 end
```

Is that what you need?

Comment: Please consider explaining what that code does and how it solves the OP's problem.

Comment: @A.Donda. Improved my answer.

Comment: @AndreiHorak. I'm glad to help). Please, mark as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, should do the required:

```
namespace :queues, :path => "queues/:name" do    
  resources :jobs
end
```

Comment: Isn't any alternative to using namespaces?

Comment: I am aware of another solution that is using `get` or `post` like `get 'queues/:name/jobs ', :to => queues/jobs#index`, :as => :new_job

Answer (score 0):

You can override `to_param` on the Queue model to return queue_name. Be aware that that will probably break your current controller model finding though.

http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/creating-vanity-urls-in-rails